# How to solve lumen migration? when it's return me this

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, lumen, laravel-migrations

[image]

How can I solve this type of error?

Comment: What command you are running?

Comment: Please post actual command and output instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Change `-create` to `--create`. It should be double dashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change command to:

```
php artisan make:migration create_books_table --create=books
```

Command thinks that you're trying to pass two arguments. You should use `--create`, as an option:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#generating-migrations